# Setting another domain in a session

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, couchdb

Here is the case:

I have a web browser that is connecting to the backend server, the backend server is communicating with the database (couchdb) that sets a session (through HTTP response) to the backend server. Now I want to send this session back to the web browser that later can communicate directly to the database, is this possible?

Im using Node.js/Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database happens to be CouchDB then yes, it is possible.

Comment: See how authentication is done in [CouchApps](http://couchapp.org/). You might use a couchapp to authenticate users and manage sessions and share those sessions with other apps under the same domain, or the other way around - authenticate users in your other app and then use the same sessions or some session tokens to get them access to CouchDB. For some example see how [Sofa](https://github.com/jchris/sofa#readme) is implemented.

Comment: The issue here is that it's the backend server that is signing in into CouchDB but I want the frontend to be able to communicate directly without the backend. Isn't the session cookie sent to backend only valid if it's from the backend?

Comment: The Frontend is not tied to the Backend .. its on another server (ip) because im using Sproutcore so its different hosting.